# How to statically compile C++ runtime into NDK/JNI library on Android?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'd like to compile a library (static but also could be shared) written in C++ so that is statically contains all the C++ runtime functionality that I use in the library, i.e. another project can simply include my .a or .so file without having to worry about further dependencies. How can I do this using the NDK/Android build system?

So far, I have

```
APP_STL := c++_static
```

in my Application.mk and build my library using

```
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

in my Android.mk after setting up the project. However, if I then pull in the resulting library into a second project (say, a dynamic library) that does not specify an STL (e.g. pure C) I get a load of symbol not found linker errors. Only when I specify to use the c++_static STL in the second project do these errors go away indicating that c++_static was not pulled into the first library. (I know this isn't surprising but it's not the behaviour I want).

Using good ol' make files and specifying build flags myself allows me to combine static libraries. My problem is coaxing the NDK build system to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

if you compile a C++ runtime statically to your lib, unfortunately another project *have to* worry about this dependency:

If several .so files are using static C++ runtimes, this can lead to corruption and crashes because of the sharing of global variables used by the runtimes.

If you compile everything (your lib and the final project) into a single .so file, you can use one static C++ runtime, and it's better then if it's declared inside the end project. Because forcing the static inclusion of the C++ runtime in your lib would prevent the end project of using a C++ runtime.